# Save to Drive using file explorer to choose the file to upload

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use "[save to drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive#savetodrive_tag_attributes)" feature form Google Developers but i want to open a file explorer to choose the file that i want to upload to Drive. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The Save to Drive button is intended to save files from your website or web application to the user's Drive. You could use an `<input type="file">` control to have users select a file, and then upload that file via a form submit to your web application. From there they could use the Save to Drive button to upload it to Drive.